# Which way is most stable and efficiency for http connection at android platform

Tags: android

As we know there are several methodology for http connection.
My social network application will start a lot of uploading, downloading and synchronization's task.
So I need stable and more efficiency connection.
How many methods for http connection in Android?
Which one is more efficiency?
Exception HttpURLConnection, how can I set up a connection to post and get ?

Comment: If you want stability, use a service on its own thread, so you don't block the ui thread waiting for the information back, and be judicious about when you decide to synchronize your content. Also, be aware that your emulator has almost zero latency, since it's most likely connected to the internet via your home network (on a phone network, your users won't be that lucky) Also, try to make use of NotificationManager and AlarmManager to bundle your synchronization attempts with the synchronization attempts of other apps. That's really what will save your users some of their precious battery life

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we are coding in java for android, we can use any of the http connections methods that are in java.
The methods in `org.apache.http` will work fine